What factors could prevent a question from appearing in the reopen review queue for a specific reviewer?
Recently, I was one of five users to vote to close a question (timeline link) on Movies & TV SE. After it was closed, I realized that my chosen close reason didn't accurately apply (my bad), so I edited the question with the intention of having it reopened.  Another user also voted to reopen the question around the same time.
I believe I checked the "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening" box when I edited the question. Based on past experiences, I expected the question to promptly appear in my reopen review queue.
In previous instances where I edited closed questions and ticked the "for reopening" box, those questions consistently appeared in my reopen review queue within seconds, allowing me to review them immediately. However, this particular question never surfaced in my queue.
When I checked the reopen review page for the question, it stated, "You are not able to review this item" (or something similar; I don't recall the exact wording). This message differed from the typical "This item is no longer reviewable" message for posts that have left the queue. The same review page revealed that at least two other users had been able to review the question in the reopen queue.
So, the system, for some reason, marked me as ineligible to review this particular question for reopening. I speculate that this might be because I was one of the initial close voters, though I'm unsure why this would prevent me from reviewing it.
To summarize the sequence of events:

A question was closed (by me and four other users).
I edited the question.
Shortly before or after my edit, another user voted to reopen the question.
The question didn't appear in my reopen review queue, even after waiting a few hours.
However, it appeared in the queues of at least two other users.
The system marked me as ineligible to review this item. I'm wondering why this happened.

(Eventually, I was one of the five users who reopened the question, with all five of us voting on the question itself, outside of the review queue, as none of us were listed on the question's reopen review page.)
I've read the Changing the question reopening experience and What are the review queues, and how do they work? posts, but this specific scenario doesn't seem to be addressed there.
I'm wondering what factors could cause a question that appears for reopening to other reviewers to not appear for a specific reviewer.

On August 7, 2024, I had a similar experience where I was one of the users to vote to close a question (timeline link). I then edited it and checked the "for reopening" box a few days later. This time, the question immediately appeared in my reopen review queue. The difference was that I was the first to vote for reopening, rather than the third. This suggests that being one of the close voters isn't the reason for a question not appearing in the reopen review queue later.

Just a guess: because you're the one that put the item into the queue (by ticking the checkbox), you're not eligible for reviewing it, i.e. you already want it reopened by putting it into the queue in the first place.

@Lino I remember a situation when I edited a closed question and ticked the 'for reopening' box. Within a few seconds or minutes after editing, that same question popped up in my reopen review queue. I was able to review it right away.

Could that have been along time ago, that it showed up in your review queue? I can't remember something like that happening to me, but you've been here for longer. I second Lino's suggestion; it reappearing for you (as the one who checked that box) simply wouldn't make sense.

@Joachim "Could that have been along time ago, that it showed up in your review queue?" I don't think that's the case here. I checked the question within minutes of editing it and seeing another user had already voted to reopen it. And I kept checking for hours afterward, but it never showed up in my review queue. Typically, an edit with the "for reopening" box checked or a reopen vote should add the post to the reopen queue right away, so I'm not sure why it didn't appear for me specifically.

@Joachim "it reappearing for you (as the one who checked that box) simply wouldn't make sense" I've actually encountered this type of scenario multiple times on different SE sites. Whenever I've edited a closed question and checked the "for reopening" box, the question has consistently appeared in my reopen review queue within a matter of seconds, without fail. So the fact that this particular question didn't appear for me is rather strange. It's definitely not the norm based on my past experiences.

Then I might be completely mistaken. I'll keep an eye out for it :)
